# appcmd.exe command causing error in win_command module

Tags: iis, ansible

I'm trying to run multiline command into the following script for urlrewrite  https redirection  under IIS through ansible playbook with the `win_command` but it shows  error even i tried to put only the first command line into the win_command :

```
- name: configure https redirection urlrewrite
  win_command: appcmd.exe set config "site1" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /"[name='Redirect to HTTPS'].match.url:"(client*)""
               appcmd.exe set config "site1" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /+"[name='Redirect to HTTPS'].conditions.[input='{REQUEST_FILENAME}',matchType='IsFile']"
               appcmd.exe set config "site1" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /+"[name='Redirect to HTTPS'].conditions.[input='{REQUEST_FILENAME}',matchType='IsDirectory']"
               appcmd.exe set config "site1" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /"[name='Redirect to HTTPS'].action.type:"Rewrite""
               appcmd.exe set config "site1" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /"[name='Redirect to HTTPS'].action.url:"client/index.html""
```

Comment: URL Rewrite module is a separate MSI download from Microsoft. So do you have that installed already on the target machine? Otherwise, appcmd must give you an error.

Comment: yes, i installed it i can do it manualy but i want to automatise it using ansible scripts

Comment: Then what exactly is the error you got? appcmd is not in Windows path, so without full path you usually cannot call it successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one command before these executed, otherwise appcmd will not find rule. I have tested it and succeeded

```
appcmd.exe set config "site1" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /+"[name='Redirect to HTTPS']"
```

[image: Here is execution result]
[image: Web.config]

Comment: hi sir, it work thank you but is there a possible way to run all line of command into the same win_command cause when i tried them all it shows error.

Comment: It is not good to do that. However, If you want to run all in a line, I suggest you write them in a script file.Then execute script by appcmd.

Comment: Yes you're right it generate some error when executed in multiple line specialy if the rule existe so i found a solution by using block in ansible like that it will execute every command alone under the block under the same task